# FFT output to PSD

Tags: fft, gnu, spectral-density

I need some help understanding the output of the FFT.

I'm working with GNU radio. I have a Signal source with output is Float type, after go through FFT transform, data will be send to my App using UDP.

My App receives the data in a byte array and then converts it into float array. So now I got the FFT output complex with format:

floatArr = {real,img,real,img .....}.

Then I calculate the PSD value from FFT output, and render chart.

But the problem is that my chart is incorrect, totally different for what GNU display

Here my GNU diagram

[image]

I calculate the PSD value with this formula;

**1:** Magnitude = 2*sqrt(re^2 + img^2)/N

**2:** PSDx = 10*Log10(Magnitude^2)

But my chart look completely different from GNU:

[image]

Please help, I currently have very little knowledge of FFT/PSD (and English too). I've tried to render this chart for weeks, actually I just blindly apply formulas.

Comment: Not really a programming question - more likely to get good answers on http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Many thanks, i hasnt found my answer yet, but this look promising.

Comment: In your second image, which is GNU Radio and which is your plot?

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih the one with title"Top Block" is GNU radio

Comment: HAve a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784385/calculating-snr-using-psd-of-captured-signal-and-noise